# Measuring Signal Strength from wifi to Iphone/Ipad

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, wifi, signal-strength

I want to get the current Wifi signal strength from an iOS device. A Google search reveals only solutions for Android devices. From the literature I gather that Apple does not allow to access hardware and so nobody can retrieve the device's signal strength in dbm through their app.

Is this correct?

Comment: Have you got the solution?

Answer (score 1):

As you say, there is no way to do this as Apple doesn't allow apps access to the necessary hardware. (There seems to have been a way to do it in [iOS 5](http://blog.guvenergokce.com/iphone-wireless-scanner-ios5/170/) but only using private APIs.)

What you can do - and what, according to [this article](http://www.ilounge.com/index.php/articles/comments/measuring-wi-fi-signal-strength-from-ios/), some apps *are* doing - is measure *network throughput* instead. While that is in no way identical with Wi-Fi signal strength, it may be a reasonable workaround for your application, depending on what it is supposed to do.

Here are some Stack Overflow questions dealing with measuring network throughput:

- [Determine the speed on internet programmatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496058/determine-the-speed-on-internet-programmatically)
- [Calculating Connection/Download Speed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed)

Comment: Is it possible using `NEHotspotConfigurationManager`? Has anybody done it? Any sample code snippet (Obj-C), please.