# How to implement Event based Real time campaigning in ios?

Tags: ios, iphone

We have already implemented beacon based real time campaigns, like setting some campaigns to some beacons and depending on the ranges we can fetch them and show it inside app as a popup. now my question is how to do the same thing using wifi?
Like: I have to monitor the wifi that associated in a particular area, then depending upon the monitored wifi I have to display the respective campaign associated with that.
Ex: I have 4 wifi networks in 1 building, all wifi is associated with one one campaign so total 4 campaigns are there, now my app should first monitor the nearest wifi and connect to that and get the respective campaign
Can anybody suggest how to achieve this?

Comment: Your question is too vague. Please add more details about what you're trying to achieve and where you're stuck

Answer (score 1):

Unlike iBeacons, currently its not possible to [detect multiple wi-fi signals](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3977273/ios-api-detect-wireless-networks) in your code.

Secondly, [measuring wi-fi signal strength](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21715690/measuring-signal-strength-from-wifi-to-iphone-ipad) is not as straight forward.

Lastly, iBeacons are based on a bluetooth standard which provide a [correlation between RSSI value (signal strength) and distance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22784516/estimating-beacon-proximity-distance-based-on-rssi-bluetooth-le) from the beacon, assuming you are using a standard beacon. This is not true for wi-fi as signal strength largely depends on the network hardware.

In spite of all these points, it is theoretically possible to create a **controlled** environment with specific wi-fi hardware which can allow you to know distance based on signal strength. But that is way too broad to be discussed in a SO question.