# iOS NSUrlConnection check upload speed

Tags: ios, file-upload

i upload files to HTTP server. I know I can get upload progres with method

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didSendBodyData:(NSInteger)bytesWritten totalBytesWritten:(NSInteger)totalBytesWritten totalBytesExpectedToWrite:(NSInteger)totalBytesExpectedToWrite
```

but is there any way to get upload speed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From a [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9496058/determine-the-speed-on-internet-programmatically) I got this answer though it was for download speed but You can also calculate upload speed form this. Measure the difference in bytes uploaded and the difference in time between calls to the delegate, then you can calculate the ongoing speed in bytes per second (or other time unit).

There is [another answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/370641/calculating-connection-download-speed) that can help you. [One more reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779600/how-to-estimate-download-time-remaining-accurately) (added from comment).

Hope this helps .. :)

Comment: One more reference http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779600/how-to-estimate-download-time-remaining-accurately