# Network Bandwith (Mbps) & Disk I/O (MB/s) using Python (Linux/Windows)

Tags: python, linux, python-3.x, ubuntu, psutil

How can we calculate the current load/usage of a computer's network and disk I/O using Python 3? Current load might mean measuring the current usage for 1 second.

Metrics of Windows/Linux systems I am most interested in includes

1. Network bandwidth (in Mbps)
2. Disk I/O (in MB/s)

*PS: Explored `psutil` but it only provides access to the cpu and memory metrics, not network and disk I/O.*

Something similar has been achieved by DigitalOcean, as shown below in their droplet metrics monitoring page

[image]

### Attempt at Calculating Network IO

```
import psutil
import time
import os

interval = 1
t0 = time.time()
upload0 = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
download0 = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv
time.sleep(interval)

t1 = time.time()
upload1 = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_sent
download1 = psutil.net_io_counters().bytes_recv

upload = (upload1 - upload0) / (t1 - t0)
download = (download1 - download0) / (t1 - t0)

print('Upload (Mbps): ', round(upload/1000000, 3))
print('Download (Mbps): ', round(download/1000000, 3))
```

Compared the results given by this code and its pretty different from that measured by Speedtest.net.

Tested on a Macbook Pro (OS X Mojave 10.14.5, Public Wifi, VPN)

**Measured by code:** 9.382 Mbps Download, 3.03 Mbps Upload

**Measured by Speedtest:** 53.05 Mbps Download, 22.89 Mbps Upload

Comment: What have you tried so far? Show us your code!

Comment: @KlausD. Good idea, updated question with a code snippet that attempts to calculate the network IO and compares it to Speed. Any ideas why its so different?

Comment: Digital Ocean has the distinct advantage that they're measuring the usage of the VM from outside, probably using Xen or Libvirt-provided metrics

Comment: @JonathonReinhart Excellent insight. I just found their [`do-agent` repo](https://github.com/digitalocean/do-agent) which is installed for monitoring the droplet metrics and they appear to be using Golang. Do you think Golang is much better suited for metrics collection compared to Python?

Comment: No. The language doesn't matter -- it all boils down to some kernel interfaces which are language agnostic.

Answer (score 0):

The diff is there because you need to flud your nics. The speedtest sends and get the full amount of data the nic can handle, thats the diff between monitor realtime bandwith and bandwith limit.
See this answer (solves this with ping terminal command but explains the logic) [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4575537/calculate-upload-download-speed-by-ping/64453796#64453796)