# Base R (or CRAN) function to run internet speed test from R?

Tags: r

Is there a function in base R (or in a package on CRAN) that runs a speed test (i.e. measures a user's download speed)?

Note: I *do not* want something that relies on libraries beyond CRAN, external scripts or any software that is outside of base R/CRAN and not already on standard operating systems (i.e. linux, mac and windows).

## Methods that come close

#### Non-CRAN package

There is a package on github (not on CRAN) that returns the user's download speed

```
install_github("https://github.com/hrbrmstr/speedtest")
library(speedtest)
speedtest::spd_download_test(speedtest::spd_best_servers())$mean
# [1] 12.9
```

#### Python script

It is possible to get the download speed via a system call to `curl`, retrieval of a python script from github, and then executing that script. E.g. `system("curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -")`.

This is nice because it can be done in R with one line of code. However, it's problematic because a) it relies on having python installed, and b) it retrieves code from github (dangerous)

Comment: What OS, windows, nix? Maybe call system(...) ?

Comment: @zx8754 for my use case I need both windows/*nix. `system`/`shell` seems reasonable. But what next. `curl` perhaps.

Comment: Hi, can this https://www.r-bloggers.com/measuring-monitoring-internet-speed-with-r/ help you?

Comment: `x <- system("someSpeedTest.exe", intern = TRUE)` ?

Comment: @Gainz good idea. Unfortunately `package ‘speedtest’ is not available (for R version 3.6.0)`

Comment: @zx8754 `system` works e.g. `system("curl -s https://raw.githubusercontent.com/sivel/speedtest-cli/master/speedtest.py | python -")` Feels a little wrong running python from R. But it works on OSX. Not sure about windows, will check

Comment: Install from GitHub? https://github.com/hrbrmstr/speedtest

Comment: Related post: https://stackoverflow.com/q/4575537/680068

Comment: @user5783745 Yes I was suggesting installing the package from github. The ``speedtest`` package is not on CRAN anyway.

Comment: If you cannot assume that the remote server's bandwidth might also be a factor, then speed-test sites won't fully work. Further, realize that some firewalls/gateways might slow down mid-stream on larger pulls (anti-streaming). If all you want is to give indication, perhaps https://rdrr.io/cran/httr/man/progress.html can help. It won't pre-determine download speeds, but it will give a visual cue to remaining time.

Comment: Use `httr::HEAD` to get the file size, `httr::GET(..., httr::add_headers(Range="bytes=1-10000"))` or so to download just a portion of the file, and time it. I have working code I can post if/when it is reopened. It is rough and prone to many issues, but it's an approximation.

Comment: You can use `system.time(ign <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(Range = "bytes=0-100000")))` to see how long it takes to download 100KB. The rest of my function really just repeats it (to quantify variance) and ensures it's big enough to actually test (vice just downloading it).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we discussed in the comments, you can download the first `n` bytes of the file, timing it, and do the math from there.

Though not base-R, it uses only the `httr` package, which is common-enough I think. You might be able to adapt this to `download.file`, though I had difficult getting `headers=` to do what I needed here.

This is an over-engineered helper-script:

```r
dl_size <- function(url) {
  tryCatch(
    as.integer(httr::HEAD(url)$headers$`content-length`),
    error = function(e) NA_integer_)
}
dl_speedtest <- function(url, size = 10000, tries = 1) {
  urlsize <- dl_size(url)
  stopifnot(isTRUE(!is.na(urlsize)))
  starts <- size * seq_len(tries)
  tries <- min(tries, floor(urlsize / size))
  counts <- sapply(
    paste(c(0, starts[-tries]), starts-1, sep = "-"),
    function(byt) {
      system.time(ign <- httr::GET(url, httr::add_headers(Range = paste0("bytes=", byt))))
    })
  browser()
  if (tries < 3) {
    elapsed <- counts["elapsed",]
    speeds <- sort(size / counts["elapsed",])
  } else {
    elapsed <- summary(counts["elapsed",])
    speeds <- summary(size / counts["elapsed",])
    expected <- summary(urlsize / (size / counts["elapsed",]))
  }
  list(elapsed = elapsed, speeds = speeds, expected = expected)
}
```

For testing, I set up a 50MiB "random" file on a personal website. Since I'd rather non inundate that site with random traffic trying to prove this, I'll just use `URL` here.

In action:

```r
dl_speedtest(URL, size=100000, tries=3)
# $elapsed
# [1] 0.20 0.11 0.09
# $speeds
# [1]  500000.0  909090.9 1111111.1
# $expected
# [1] 102.40  56.32  46.08

dl_speedtest(URL, size=100000, tries=5)
# $elapsed
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   0.080   0.090   0.090   0.094   0.100   0.110 
# $speeds
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#  909091 1000000 1111111 1076263 1111111 1250000 
# $expected
#    Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
#   40.96   46.08   46.08   48.13   51.20   56.32
```

Like I said, over-engineered, but I was playing with it. You can/should reduce the code quite a bit.